# The allocate function of the dinero.js library never ends

Tags: javascript, dinero.js

I’m using the [dinero.js](https://github.com/dinerojs/dinero.js/) library in my application with nestjs, but for these parameters the allocate function never ends or gives an error:

```
const d = dinero({"amount":337582417582417600000,"currency":{"code":"USD","base":10,"exponent":2},"scale":19});

allocate(d, [0.3, 0.7]);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: does the first parameter have to be dinero object

Comment: `allocate(dinero({"amount":337582417582417600000,"currency":{"code":"USD","base":10,"exponent":2},"scale":18}), [0.3, 0.7])
`
i meant like this

Comment: @cmgchess I updated my question to reflect that I am using a money object, thank you for your response.